# can i c.connect once in a access.form instead of each form.event?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access

i do have ms.sql backend and ms.access frontend and always retrive the data shown in a form by following code:

```vb
    Private Sub combo_search_Change()
        Dim c As New ADODB.Connection
        Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

        Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
        Dim Srv As Variant
        Dim db As Variant
        Dim UID As Variant
        Dim pwd As Variant

        Dim strSQL As String

        Dim tbl_name As String
        tbl_name = "tblSQLxxx"



        Srv = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT Server FROM [" & tbl_name & "]")(0)
        '-------------------------------------------------------
        db = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT db FROM [" & tbl_name & "]")(0)
        '-------------------------------------------------------
        UID = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT uid FROM [" & tbl_name & "]")(0)
        '-------------------------------------------------------
        pwd = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT pwd FROM [" & tbl_name & "]")(0)
        '---------------------------------------------------------------------------

        c.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & _
                              Trim([Srv]) & ";Database=" & Trim([db]) &""
```

and then calling with c.open & rs.open the needed data. as i have couple of list.boxes filled on the form, i place on each "on change" "exit" ... this above connection code and therefore flooding my code. is there a way to place the connection.code once in the form and then only call "c.open"&"rs.open" in all the "change/exit/entry" parts of the vba.code?

Comment: Standard approach would be to create a `DBConnection` (for example) function, which returns the configured Connection object, and call that function from your form code.

Comment: Hi tim, ty, this solved my problem, will save me a lot of lines, thanks